# Напишите функцию, которая возвращает ряд Фибоначчи до определенного числа. Нельзя использовать let и var, только const

Tags: javascript, ряды, const, числа-фибоначчи

Пример работы функции

```
fibonacci(8);
Вывод: [0,1,1,2,3,5]
```

Нашел как генерировать ряд фибоначчи методами массива:

```
const fibonacci = n =>
  Array.from({ length: n }).reduce(
    (acc, val, i) => acc.concat(i > 1 ? acc[i - 1] + acc[i - 2] : i),
    []
  );
```

Но не могу понять как генерировать ряд до числа не большего поступающему в функцию без применения let и var.

Comment: Ограничение на использование `let` и `var` чисто формально можно обойти, например так: `let a = b; a = a + c;` -> `const a = [b]; a[0] = a[0] + c;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант без рекурсии:

```js
function fibonacci(limit) {
  if (limit <= 0) return [];
  if (limit === 1 ) return [0];

  const result = [0, 1];

  while (true) {
    const sum = result[result.length - 2] + result[result.length - 1];
    if (sum >= limit) break;
    result.push(sum);
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(fibonacci(0));
console.log(fibonacci(1));
console.log(fibonacci(2));
console.log(fibonacci(8));
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать примерно так:

```js
const fib = (
  lim,
  res = [0, 1],
  next = res.slice(-2).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
) => {
  return lim < next ? res : fib(lim, [...res, next]);
};

console.log(`fib(6)`, fib(6));
console.log(`fib(10)`, fib(10));
console.log(`fib(20)`, fib(20));
```